# Insert bank detail in email if the user choose to pay with bank transfer

Tags: rules, emails, commerce

I want to add a to order checkout emails the bank account details managed by [commerce_bank_transfer](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_bank_transfer) module.
I create a rule for the order with the bank transfer payment method but I'm not undertanding how to add in the mail my site's bank account infos.

I tryed to add this code to the email

```
<?php
   $payment_method = commerce_payment_method_load('bank_transfer');
   echo commerce_bank_transfer_bank_details($commerce_order->order_id, $payment_method);  
?>
```

I did some test and in the mail there is nothing where I was expecting my bank info.

Reading commerce_bank_transfer module I saw that commerce_bank_transfer_bank_details function request a 'setting' key in the $payment_method array but if I retry the payment method by

```
commerce_payment_method_load('bank_transfer');
```

I have no 'setting' key.

How can I retry the setting from a payment method?

Answer (score 2):

I solve with this code:

```
<?php 
$payment_method = commerce_payment_method_instance_load($commerce_order->data['payment_method']);
echo commerce_bank_transfer_bank_details($commerce_order->order_id, $payment_method); 
?>
```

[commerce_payment_method_instance_load()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.module/function/commerce_payment_method_instance_load/7) function need in input a string like

'bank_transfer|commerce_payment_bank_transfer'

and it returns a paymente method with all data [ setting included ]